# How to fix mysqli_fetch_array? I use php, mysqli and html

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, syntax-error

i have a problem with my php code, it gives me the error of : Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\funcion2.php on line 69

I dont know how to solve it. i need some help pls, i need to finish the project.

```html
<?php
//Conexion a la BBDD
include 'config.php';
session_start();

if($_REQUEST['cur']){$_SESSION['cur2']=$_REQUEST['cur'];}
$cur=$_SESSION['cur2'];
$str=$cur;
$cur=explode ('|', $str);
echo $cur[0];

if ($_REQUEST['alu']){$_SESSION['alu2']=$_REQUEST['alu'];}
$alu=$_SESSION['alu2'];
$str2=$alu;
$alu=explode ('|', $str2);


/*primera consulta*/
$query  = 'select * from curso';
$res=mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

/*segunda consulta*/
$query2 = 'select * from alumnos where cod_curso=$cur[0]';
$res2=mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);



?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>


<body>

<form name="form1" method="post">
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  
  <label>Curso</label>
  <select name="cur" onchange="this.form.submit() ;">
    <option value="<?php echo $cur[1] ?>" ></option>
    <?php 
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
     {
   
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row[0]."|".$row[1]?>"><?php echo htmlentities($row[1]); ?>
   </option>
   
   <?php } ?>
 
  </select>
   
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label>Alumnos</label>     
   
   <select name="alu">
   
    <option value="<?php echo $alu[0]?>"</option>
    <?php 
     while ($value=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) 
     {
   
   ?>
  <?php foreach ($alu as $key => $value){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $value[0]."|".$value[1]?>"><?php echo htmlentities($value[1]);?>
   </option>
   <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
    
</div>

 <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" hidden />
 
</form>
<?php

echo "Tu curso es: ".$cur[1]."<br/>";
echo "El alumno es: ".$alu[1]."<br/>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

There is the problem 
[.The error os mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK1jq.jpg)

My database have these 2 tables:
Table alumnos and Table curso

[My tables and the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK1jq.jpg)

I modified the parameters without @ and the second mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php `$value=mysqli_fetch_array($conexion, $cur)` should be something more like `$value=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)` as it exppect 1st arg to be results, but i'm not posting this as an answer because both of @tadman comment should be taken into consideration  before going any further.

Comment: I delete the @ from the $_REQUEST. How can I get the data from the second select, the first select show me the data but the second doesn't work. I'm sorry by my English, I'm from Spain.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sending the connection to the while loop for alumnos?

`while ($value=mysqli_fetch_array($conexion, $cur))`

It's expecting a DB array result, not the connection.

*******EDIT
Now that I've taken a look, you still have errors in this section.

```
<?php   
    while ($value=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) 
    {
?>
<?php 
    foreach ($alu as $key => $value){
?>
     <option value="<?php echo $value[0]."|".$value[1]?>">
        <?php echo htmlentities($value[1]);?>
     </option>
     <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Why do you have a for each loop inside a while loop? Unless `$value` has data that you need to loop inside each row, it is already being looped by the while loop and you would not need the for each.

Comment: I change it for <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)), but the error persists, it says that mysqli_fetch_array expects 1 parameter to be mysqli_result. Sorry I'm newbie at php, I have practiced only since 2 weeks

Comment: I put a foreach because sql says that that tipe of data in alumnos.nombre can´t be a string so i have to do a foreach no?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how your data is structured but you `$value` in the while loop and then you're looping `$alu` in the foreach and over writing the original `$value` variable. Let me take look at your structure and I'll update my answer.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80eLEi2L7YaUjZBQmsxWmtNck0/view?usp=sharing . Here is my database